Issues with setting up next-intl with app router
I am quite new to programming and I can't get the below code to work.
enter image description here
This is my app structure.
This is the code for my middleware.js:
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';
import { locales, localePrefix } from './navigation';

export default createMiddleware({
    locales: ['bg', 'en'],
    defaultLocale: 'bg',
});

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/', '/bg/:path*', '/en/:path*'], // Ensure this matches all paths including locales
};


i18n.js:
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';
import { getRequestConfig } from 'next-intl/server';
    
    // Can be imported from a shared config
    const locales = ['bg', 'en'];
    
    
    export default getRequestConfig(async ({ locale }) => {
        console.log(`Received locale: ${locale}`); // Add this line for debugging
        // Validate that the incoming `locale` parameter is valid
        if (!locales.includes(locale)) notFound();
    
        return {
            messages: (await import(`./locales/${locale}.json`)).default,
        };
    });    


layout. jsx:
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { NextIntlClientProvider } from 'next-intl';
import "./globals.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
    title: "Create Next App",
    description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default async function RootLayout({ children, params: { locale } }) {
    const messages = (await import(`../../locales/${locale || 'bg'}.json`)).default;

    return (
        <html lang={locale}>
            <body className={inter.className}>
                <NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
                    <Navbar />
                    {children}
                </NextIntlClientProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
  

If I manually change
const messages = (await import(`../../locales/${locale || 'bg'}.json`)).default;

to
const messages = (await import(`../../locales/${locale || 'en'}.json`)).default;

The website updates accordingly, otherwise no matter what I do - it stays in Bulgarian. I tried adding console logs and it seems that both the middleware and i18n are handling the selected language from the link properly but it's not being applied to layout.jsx
I am trying to display the website in both English and Bulgarian, depending on the link accessed (http://localhost:3000/en and http://localhost:3000/bg) but no matter what i do, i am only getting the Bulgarian version.
